# Products now showing up in category overview in new store view

Tags: magento2, category-products

I'm trying out Magento 2 on my local machine (WAMP) to see if it's suitable for the webshop of a friend.

After installing the software and the sample data, I tried configuring 3 different storeviews with different languages.

This is a category in the default store view:

[image]

As soon as I switch to a none default store views, the category list is empty

[image]

The product detail pages do work in both store views.

Anyone any idea what I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

I fixed this problem by manually reindexing and flushing the cache